# iOS application goes to dashboard when it comes from background to foreground?

Tags: ios, objective-c, application-lifecycle

I am experiencing a problem with switching app from background to foreground.

It is a tab bar based app. If i launch the app immediately it redirects to the view controller where i left off. but if I launch it after 5/10 min(basically after some period). It launches the app from initial screen.

From google, I read that if my app is in background for a while, it will be killed from by the Operating system based on the need of RAM for other application.

**1. is this the only reason for the above problem or any other reasons
?**

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PreservingandRestoringState.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH28-SW5

Answer (score 0):

This is the main reason it can happen. You can maybe increase the time this takes to happen by implementing the `didReceiveMemoryWarning` method and adding sufficient code to `free()` / `release` a lot of resources that can be later recreated. This will give you a chance of not getting killed in some cases and maybe buy you some time.